# Supersized : give each slide a classname

Tags: javascript, jquery, supersized

i'm looking for a way to give a classname to the caption box of Supersized, depending on the current slide (ie. odd / even class).

Is it possible ?

```
  if($(vars.current_slide).is('li:even')){
      $(vars.slide_caption).addClass('oddSlide');
}
  else {
      $(vars.slide_caption).removeClass('oddSlide');
    }
```

The code above only works for the first caption. If there is 3 slides / captions, only the first will have the oddslide class, not the others.
...
Any help please ?

EDIT :
I get it, vars.current_slide returns the number of the current slide, when i thought it returns an object.

```
if( isOdd(vars.current_slide)) {

                $(vars.slide_caption).addClass('oddSlide');
             }
            else {

                $(vars.slide_caption).removeClass('oddSlide');
            }
```

Where isOdd() is a basical function to test odd/even :

```
function isOdd(num) { return num % 2;}
```

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. What have you tried so far ?

Comment: can you please also show the HTML markup?

Comment: Hi, i get it. I have to wait 8 hours to post the solution. The thing is, vars.current_slide returns an number, not an object, as I expected.

Comment: Not my first post on SO, but thank you for your welcome :)

Comment: Perhaps easier to read: `$(vars.slide_caption).toggleClass('oddSlide', isOdd(vars.current_slide));` using [`.toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/#toggleClass-className-switch)

Comment: I'll try it, much more easier to read. I didn't know that use of toggleClass(), thanks.